# clang-3.4 binary for mingw32

Tags: clang

I was wondering if there is a pre-built clang-3.4 (stable-release) binary for mingw32 (www.mingw.org) for download? I do not want to use the VS version b/c I only use gcc and I don't want future compatibility issues (such as VS compiled opencv shared libraries crashing mingw/gcc compiled applications).

I checked http://llvm.org/releases/download.html. They had  "Experimental Clang Binaries for Mingw32/x86" for 3.3 and 3.2, but not for the new 3.4 release.

Thanks,